# PHP: I'm inserting 1 record in the database, but it is automatically inserting 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm inserting 1 record in the database, but it is automatically inserting 2 records..
Does anyone know how to solve this?

When I execute this code ALWAYS insert 2 records

My code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Source\Database\Connect;

$exec = Connect::getInstance()->query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, document) 
    VALUE ('Rodrigo', 'Gomes', 'rodrigoaraujo990@gmail.com', '1123123')");
```

I use the singleton pattern to make my connection to the database and use the PDO class to make an insertion in the database
Connect class:

```
class Connect
{
    private const HOST = "localhost";
    private const DBNAME = "database";
    private const USER = "root";
    private const PASSWD = "";
    private const OPTIONS = [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
    ];

    private static $instance;

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public static function getInstance(): PDO
    {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            try{
                self::$instance = new PDO(
                    "mysql:host=" . self::HOST . ";dbname=" . self::DBNAME,
                    self::USER,
                    self::PASSWD,
                    self::OPTIONS
                );
            }catch (PDOException $exception){
                echo $exception->getMessage("");
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private final function __construct()
    {
    }

    private final function __clone()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: there's a syntax error in the code you posted: `echo $exception->getMessage()";`.

Comment: $exec = Connect::getInstance()->query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, document) 
    VALUE ('Rodrigo', 'Gomes', 'rodrigoaraujo990@gmail.com', '1123123')"); This query() insert 2 records in database, but i want only 1 record....

Comment: You must be running the script twice, it won't insert two rows by itself.

Comment: Check your PHP access log.

Comment: Not me, man .. My code is this and insert it 2 times

Comment: Maybe the client is sending two requests. Are you using AJAX to submit the data? Make sure you're preventing the default form submission.

Comment: how do I do it, lol.. error_log="C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log" dont has nothing...

Comment: I sent it through the browser, without a form.. Nothing more. lol

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),  or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: I refresh the browser and 2 new rows appear in the database

Comment: I haven't tried it yet ..

Comment: The problem was the google chrome browser, it had a bug .. I tested it on another browser and it is normal

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the google chrome browser, it had a bug .. I tested it on another browser and it is normal Thanks!!!!